# Read a file using that is opened with O_DIRECT flag

Tags: python, caching

I need to read a file without any effect of caching. So I open the file with os.open() with the O_DIRECT flag and read with os.read() this way:

```
import os, sys
fd = os.open( "foo.txt", os.O_RDONLY|os.O_DIRECT)
# fd = os.open( "foo.txt", os.O_RDONLY)
readBytes = os.read(fd, os.path.getsize("foo.txt"))
print(readBytes)
os.close( fd)
```

The problem is that if I use the os.O_DIRECT flag the code, the code does not work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    readBytes = os.read(fd, os.path.getsize("foo.txt"))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

However, it works perfectly, if I remove this flag (the line in comment)! Please suggest!

Comment: Can you say what you want without saying "caching"? This sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: In short, by avoid caching, I mean direct I/O. For this case please assume, I need to make os.open with O_DIRECT flag work with os.read :)

Comment: I mean, can you ask what wish to do, instead of asking how you'd fix your answer for what you're trying to do. Wanting to avoid caching is deeply weird and it smells funny. And that `read` syscall isn't going to give you all the bytes, and you aren't checking how many you got. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @ChadMiller: the file I am reading is a very small file. Could you please explain why read syscall will not give all bytes? Regarding caching, I would like to eliminate or reduce cache effects or in other word, I want to make sure the file is being read directly, and not be given back from the cache.

Comment: read() is allowed to give you any number of bytes. The number you're specifying there is the maximum you're willing to accept.

Comment: yes, because, I want to read the whole file.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking the OS doesn't know what's on the disk. That could be true if the disk is written to by many computers at once. That isn't likely, though. In any case, I answered your actual question below. The filesystem type you're on doesn't support O_DIRECT.

Comment: By "you're specifying the maximum", I mean every use of `read` syscall specifies the maximum bytes to read, not the actual or minimum. It mattered when we used languages were we have to allocate space ahead of time like declaring a var as 500 bytes long, and asking the OS to read into it, but NEVER MORE THAN 500 because that would cause a crash. SO, read will return from zero to N bytes when you say `read(fd, buf, N)` and return the actual number it successfully stored, and that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filesystem doesn't support the `O_DIRECT` flag.

`$ man open` and see the Errors section.

Comment: I looked at the man page and it seems it is supported  under Linux in kernel version 2.4.10. Mine is 3.x.x. So should not it be there? I also don't see any error similar to mine!

Comment: Search for the word "ERRORS" and "EINVAL".